# Is it possible for an Event Hub Consumer to also produce events on the same Hub?

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is it possible for an EH consumer to also produce messages in some cases, using the same EH?

I am trying the below code in Java. Two identical consumers are running simultaneously. They receive messages fine, but if they try to send a message on a certain condition, that particular message isn't received by anyone.

```
    EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(CONNECTION_STRING, EH_NAME)
            .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
            .buildAsyncConsumerClient();

    EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(CONNECTION_STRING, EH_NAME)
            .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
            .buildProducerClient();

    consumer.receiveFromPartition("0", EventPosition.latest()).subscribe(event -> 
    {
        String ev = event.getData().getBodyAsString();
        System.out.println("Event arrived: " + ev);

        if (ev.compareTo("TARGET") == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\tCreating echo for TARGET");
            EventDataBatch batch = producer.createBatch();
            batch.tryAdd(new EventData("TARGET -- response"));
            producer.send(batch);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to publish and consume within the same host application.  In your code snippet, you're attempting to add an event to an `EventDataBatch` but not verifying the return of `tryAdd` - if your event is too large, you will not know that it wasn't accepted into the batch and your `send` call is empty.  The event body in your snippet is small enough that this isn't a concern, but I'd recommend inspecting the `tryAdd` return and taking appropriate action for real application data.

One thing that you may want to check is how many partitions your Event Hub has and which of those you're actively reading, as it is possible that your application isn't reading from the partition where your event was published.

In your snippet, the consumer is reading from partition "0" only; it will not see events from other partitions.  When your producer publishes the event, it is not requesting any specific partition, which indicates to the Event Hubs service that it should assign the partition.  The Event Hubs service will distribute events to partitions evenly using a round-robin approach.

You may want to consider [publishing events to a specific partition](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/PublishEventsToSpecificPartition.java) to ensure that your consumers can read them, or using the `EventProcessorClient` to [read from all partitions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/EventProcessorClientSample.java).

One other thing that I'll note is that there is little value in using an `EventDataBatch` for a single event; you're paying for the cost of measuring the event size which can help you avoid an exception if the event is too large, but if you're confident that your typical event size is not at risk of being overly large, you'll gain some efficiency by using the [send overload that accepts an iterable](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/main/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/EventHubProducerClient.java#L219).

Comment: Thanks, got this working by following the example in your first link. which is slightly different from what I had before. Maybe this has something to do with me not doing checkpointing before, which I had assumed I didn't need.